# How to secure first digits and display last 3 digits?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uilabel

I have text field and the data that i entered in text field has to be displayed on label with some secure text.

for example if i have entered 123456789 data in text field then the data in label must be shown as ******789.

How it can be done?

Comment: I know only securetext entry set to yes only . but for that whole text will be secured. so I'm looking for this and didn't find any that gives better result.

Comment: This has nothing to do with UITextField or its secure text entry. You are talking about updating a label's text. Simply update the string as needed before setting the label's text.

Comment: @saikiran is there any limit for input value ?

Comment: yes 15 @ParvendraSingh

Comment: @rmaddy but that label text must be the text that i entered in textfield and the text in the label has to secured as like example that i mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for your query,

```
   -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
           NSString * textFieldString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
           NSMutableString * str1 = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:textFieldString];

       if(str1.length > 3){
         NSRange r = NSMakeRange(0, [str1 length] - 3);
         [str1 replaceCharactersInRange:r withString:[[NSString string] stringByPaddingToLength:r.length withString:@"*" startingAtIndex:0]];
         NSLog(@"test string---- > %@",str1);
       }
     }
```